# Implementing Merkle Tree off chain

Tags: merkle

I have basic understanding of Merkle Tree and how it works, now I am implementing it to my smart contract as whitelist verification.

I stored the root in smart contract, implemented the verify function in smart contract (with proof as parameter).

To verify with smart contract, we will call verify function in smart contract, and pass in the proof. Now this is what troubled me. To get the proof, we need the whole list of leaves, generate a tree, and get the proof.

What is the best way to implement this? I have a few ideas in mind.

1. Generate the tree, and get the proof of each leaves, store in a key value pair. When the leaf (key) needs verification, get the proof (value) and send to smart contract for verification.
2. Generate the tree every time when users ask for the proof.

Most tutorial don't show the off chain part.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: A while ago I wrote an article about Merkle Tree implementation in Javascript. It could help you. Take a look: https://medium.com/coinmonks/merkle-tree-a-simple-explanation-and-implementation-48903442bc08

Comment: @JeremyThen thanks for your article. I am using merkletreejs. My question is, I had generated the root and stored it in smart contract, and implemented the verify function. I intend to use a site that connect to wallet, and call the smart contract's verify function. The function needs the proof. What is the efficient way to obtain the proof? Store them all in off chain database? Or generate it from whitelist every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set of leaves is immutable, meaning, once generated they will not change (no new leave is going to be added). Then you could generate the proof for a specific leave when needed and then cache it. Generate the proof only when needed and then you can cache it if you know it will be used often. If not, there's no need to cache it, it could be generated when needed.

If any of the leaves are going to be used often, then you can create the tree and persist it/cache it somewhere, so, when someone wants to generate a proof for a specific leaf, they can do it in `O(log n)` time, which is really efficient.

Now, the problem is if the set of leaves set is going to be mutable if more leaves are going to be added to the set. Because you will not be able to simply generate the tree once and reuse it. You would need to generate the tree every time you want to generate a proof for a leaf if the leaves set has been modified because the root would obviously change.

If the set of leaves is going to be mutable, then somehow the contract needs to know when the root changes and update its root

That's one of the advantages of blockchain, since the transactions are stored in an immutable block, there's no need to generate a Merkle tree every time it is not needed. So, check the requirements of your needs and verify if the set of leaves will not be mutable or if there's something else you can do to make sure that they will not.

**Conclusion**

If the leaves set is immutable, generate the tree only once, and it would take `O(log n)` to generate the proof for any leave. This is efficient and can be done at any time.

Saving the proof for each leave is space-consuming. No need to do that if you store the Merkle tree since it's really efficient to generate any proof from it.

There's no need to generate the tree and then the proof every time, unless the set of leaves is mutable, which I don't recommend you keep a mutable set of leaves. Check if you can somehow avoid it being mutable, and organize them in "block" in case it's needed.